# Delete Status Updates/Comments on Company Pages using LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I am able to connect to Company pages and update Status and Comments using the API. I cannot find any way to delete either status or comments from the API. Is that possible?

Regards,
Sonal

Comment: delete is not accessible using api.